# Use of wire inside an always block?

Tags: verilog, digital-logic

Can I use a wire inside an always block?
    Like for example:

```
        wire [3:0]a;
        assign a=3;

        always @(c)
           begin
                d=a+c;
           end
```

It got compiled without throwing any error. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use a wire's value inside an always block, you just can not assign a value to a wire in always or initial block.

The only real difference between a wire and reg is the syntax for assigning values.

In the above example d could also have been created as a wire, these are equivalent:

```
reg [3:0] answer_reg;
always @* begin
  answer_reg = a + c;
end

wire [3:0] answer_wire;
assign answer_wire = a + c;
```

Comment: What kind of hardware does this infer? Like in the above example, d is an adder who gets one input as c and the other as 'a' which is a constant. So, will 'a' be a wire connected to Vdd and gnd making a 3?

Comment: Yes effectively, a is constant pattern logic `4'b0011` which can be though of as `GND GND VDD VDD`. wire vs reg has very little to do with hardware, they are really simulator optimisations.