# wire in always block/case statement - Verilog

Tags: case, verilog, system-verilog

Following is a sample code that uses case statement and always @(*) block. I don't get how the always block is triggered and why it works even when x is declared as wire.

```
wire [2:0] x = 0;
always @(*)
begin
case (1'b1)
  x[0]: $display("Bit 0 : %0d",x[0]);
  x[1]: $display("Bit 1 : %0d",x[1]);
  x[2]: $display("Bit 2 : %0d",x[2]);
  default: $display("In default case");
endcase
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know, `reg` can be driven by a `wire`, we can definitely use a `wire` as the right hand side of the assignment in any procedural block.

Here, your code checks which bit of `x` is `1'b1` (of course giving *priority* to zeroth bit). Lets say `x` changes to `3'b010`. Then, `Bit 1` shall be displayed and so on. Now, if `x=3'b011` then `Bit 0` is displayed since zeroth bit is checked first.

As you can see, there is no **assignment** to `x`, the procedural block only reads its value. Moreover, the system task `$display` also reads the value of `x`.

There is no change of signal value from this block. Hence, this code works fine. If, by chance, we had something like `x[0] = ~x[0]` instead of `$display`, then this code shall provide compilation issues.

More information can be found at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125760/use-of-wire-inside-an-always-block) and [this](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/) links.

Comment: Thank you. can we use $fwrite or immediate assertion on wire from this always block?

Comment: Yes. Immediate assertions can be written here. But it depends how you use them. If by any means, the value of `x` changes, then it will result in error. I'm not sure of $fwrite, but  I guess, it should also work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this always block does not assign a value to a x, but it just checks a value of x. So it's a legal use of wire.

Comment: Thank you. can we use $fwrite or immediate assertion on wire from this always block?

Answer (score 1):

So, the explanation to the part of your question about how **always @(*)** is triggered is as follows :

**"Nets and variables that appear on the right-hand side of assignments, in subroutine calls, in case and conditional expressions, as an index variable on the left-hand side of assignments, or as variables in case item expressions shall all be included in always @(*)."**

Ref: **IEEE Std 1800-2012** **Sec 9.4.2.2**

As an extension of @sharvil111's answer, if your code was something like this

```
always @(*)
begin

case (sel)
x[0]: $display("Bit 0 : %0d",x[0]);
x[1]: $display("Bit 1 : %0d",x[1]);
x[2]: $display("Bit 2 : %0d",x[2]);
default: $display("In default case");

endcase
end
```

The procedural block would be triggered whenever there is a change in **sel** signal or **x** i.e. it would be equivalent to **always @(sel or x)**.

Comment: So, in my current case, I presume that it must be equivalent to always @ (x), am I correct? Thank you for your response. can we use $fwrite or immediate assertion on wire from this always block? e.g. `assert (x[0] == 1'b0)` or `$fwrite(file,"x is%0d",x)`?